# Given a table with multiple pages on a webpage how can I access data for all pages from chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 100 rows which is displayed 20 rows at a time on a webpage. I can view the next 20 rows by clicking "next page" which updated the table view on my webpage. I can access the data for each batch of 20 rows via the developer/inspect browser tools. Is there anyway to get this for all 100 rows at once? The webpage is only accessible after logging in, i.e. the data is not publicly available.

Comment: Please share what you have attempted.

Comment: Share your code, so that we can help

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the page is doing.

If the 100 rows aren't loaded on the browser at once then no you can't get them. For example the page may be calling a web service to load 20 at a time.

You would have to understand how the page acquires the rows and then replicate that with some javascript in order to pull back more at once.

You may also be able to use the console/debugging tools to edit the code on the page to make it load more at once. Really it's very dependent on the specifics of what the page is doing.